# How to flat list after adding new element in the beginning in groovy

Tags: groovy

I would need to `flatten` the list after adding one new item at the beginning:

```
myLst= "a,b,c,x"
myLst= myLst.tokenize(",")
def pick = myLst.find {'x' }
def newList = myLst.minus(pick)
newList.add(0, 'all')
println(newList.flatten())
```

But I get is:

```
[all, a
b
c]
```

I would need:

```
[all 
a
b
c]
```

Anybody can help me how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would need:
>
> ```
> [all   
>  a  
>  b  
>  c]
> ```

This should give you the desired result:

```
myLst= "a,b,c,x"
myLst= myLst.tokenize(",")
def pick = myLst.find {'x' }
def newList = myLst - 'x'
newList.add 0, 'all'
def result = newList.join('\n ')
println "[${result}]"
```

Output:

```
[all
 a
 b
 c]
```

Could organize that a lot of ways.  For ex:

```
myLst= "a,b,c,x"
newList= ['all'] + myLst.tokenize(",") - 'x'
result = newList.join('\n ')
println "[${result}]"
```

Comment: @andrej-istomin Thank you for the suggested edit but I have rejected because it eliminated the whitespace that was included in the original question describing the desired output.  The change you made would make the output inconsistent with the code.  Notice that the `.join` is joining on a newline followed by a space, not just a newline.  That was intentional to generate the output requested in the question.

Comment: @andrej-istomin I see now that you also edited the question so now the code in my answer no longer matches that.  I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @janfi86 The code currently in the answer above will generate output that is consistent with the original question.  The question has been edited to remove the leading whitespace in front of elements.  If that is the intended output, then replaceing `newList.join('\n ')` with `newList.join('\n')` should be consistent with that.  Sorry for any confusion.